# Как изменить цвет иконок в меню android приложения?

Tags: android

Как изменить цвет иконок в меню android приложения? Нужно цвет кнопок сделать белым.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой файл styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="titleTextColor">@color/colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Это не colorAccent. Если бы это было так у меня бы цвет иконок был бы розовым...

Answer (score 1):

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
...
 android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
 app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Или вместо `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">`

напишите  `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`